# List<Dictionary> foreach get value

Tags: c#, asp.net, dictionary

```
List<Dictionary<string, object>> data = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
Dictionary<string, Object> objs = new Dictionary<string, object>();
for (int i = 1; i <= onlineolanlar.Count; i++)
{
    objs.Add(i.ToString(), new userLevel() { UserID = userID.ToString(), Presence = UserLevelBul.ToString() });
}
foreach (var item5 in objs.Values)
{
    //How can I access item5 properties here??
}
```

Hi all,

How can I reach the values of that foreach loop?

`item5` should have properties  `userid` and `userlevelbul` but I can't reach them.

Comment: Explain this in as much detail as you can : `in item5 there are userid and userlevelbul but i cant reach them`

Comment: Create a type with `UserID, Presence, etc..` and add that type to `objs` instead of adding anonymous type.

Comment: when i write item5. it only shows equals.gethashcode etc. No userid...

Comment: declare your dictionary `objs` as `Dictionary<string, userLevel>`,

Comment: There are very few times you legitimately need to use the `Object` type directly. 99% of the time there's a more specific type you want to be using (`userLevel`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You declared your dictionary `objs` as `Dictionary<string, object>`. But in fact you only want to add (and later use) entries of type `userLevel`.

So simply declare the dictionary with the correct types:

```
Dictionary<string, userLevel> objs = new Dictionary<string, userLevel>();
```

Then you can use it straight forward:

```
foreach (var item5 in objs.Values)
{
     Console.WriteLine(item5.userID)
     Console.WriteLine(item5.Presence)
}
```

because now the elements in `objs.Values` as well as `item5` are of type `userLevel`.

Answer (score 0):

Either use `userLevel` with your `Dictionary<string, Object>` instead of `Object` or use [Explicit casting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions#explicit-conversions) (if you for some reason can't change `object`):

```
foreach (var item5 in objs.Values)
{
     string userId = ((userLevel)item5).UserID;
     // or
     // string userId = (item5 as userLevel).UserID;
}
```